# Is there a shorter way to express this haskell idiom?

Tags: code-golf, tips, haskell

Every so often I have a function of type `a -> b` and a function of type `b -> b -> c` and I would like a function of type `a -> a -> c`.  For example if I wanted to check the second element of each two tuples were equal

```
snd :: (a , b) -> b
(==) :: Eq a => a -> a -> Bool
```

And I want something of type

```
Eq b => (a, b) -> (c, b) -> Bool
```

The best way I have found to do this so far is

```
f g z=(.g).z.g
```

Which is ok, but it feels unneccessarily complex for something that is this simple.
The pointfree representation is even worse:

```
flip=<<((.).).(.).flip(.)
```

Additionally it feels like this idiom should be representable with some sort of abstraction (it feels a lot like `(<*>)`).  I attempted to find a replacement by abstracting our functions to functors, the result is not very enlightening

```
flip=<<(fmap.).fmap.flip fmap ::
  Functor f => f a -> (a -> a -> b) -> f (f b)
```

Is there a shorter way to express this idea?  Particularly the pointfree version?

Comment: There is [`on`](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=on) but you need to `import Data.Function`.

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled upon this question in the related questions list of [How to golf a fork in Haskell?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/233116/78410). Now that I have a better understanding of combinator golf, I gave it a try.

Primer: Haskell supports a few combinators including the standard S, B, C, K, I:

```haskell
-- I
id = \x -> x
-- K
pure = \x y -> x  -- 1 byte shorter than `const`
-- S
(<*>) = \x y z -> x z (y z)
-- B
(.) = \x y z -> x (y z)
-- C
flip = \x y z -> x z y
-- Variations of S
(>>=) = \x y z -> y (x z) z
(=<<) = \x y z -> x (y z) z
liftA2 = \f g h x -> f (g x) (h x)  -- part of latest Prelude
```

Now, there are two possible forms to convert to pointfree:

```
v1 :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> a -> c)
v1 f g x y = f (g x) (g y)
v2 :: (a -> b) -> (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> a -> c)
v2 f g x y = g (f x) (f y)
```

The following are all the various reductions I tried (along with typechecking):

```hs
import Control.Applicative

type On a b c = (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
fref :: On a b c
fref g h x y=g(h x)(h y)
f1 :: On a b c
f1=(flip flip<*>).(.).((.).)
f2 :: On a b c
f2 z g=(.g).z.g
f3 :: On a b c
f3=(flip=<<).(.).((.).)
f4 :: On a b c
f4=liftA2(.)(flip(.)).(.)
f5 :: On a b c
f5=((.).(flip(.))<*>).(.)

type On2 a b c = (a -> b) -> (b -> b -> c) -> a -> a -> c
fref' :: On2 a b c
fref' g h x y=h(g x)(g y)
f1' :: On2 a b c
f1' g=((.g).).(.g)
f2' :: On2 a b c
f2'=liftA2(.)((.).flip(.))(flip(.))
f3' :: On2 a b c
f3' g z=(.g).z.g
f4' :: On2 a b c
f4'=(.).(.).flip(.)<*>flip(.)
f5' :: On2 a b c
f5'=(.).(.).q<*>q;q=flip(.)
f6' :: On2 a b c
f6' g=(.g).((.g).)
f7' :: On2 a b c
f7'=r<*>r;r=(.).flip(.)
f8' :: On2 a b c
f8'=s<*>s;s x=(.)(.x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZHNjoIwEIDvfYqJF8om20TEn6g1MV432cM@AbK0kq2Abd2IL89OQRG6B6bN9Osw8/WUmJ9MqabJz1WpLRzKwupSsX1VqTxNbP6bEWLrKoPPAhI4Qgoc6BHed9CGNHSRJm2i3Sd9SInQmYD1ur/bJSSc4AY1lxTXEEMdEjEdc1NOhcorcGH7tgsZZfi5gGw0ZiO4g@SUyZDdmSRiNj6edaX4djuuEo@xmKtc2H2Epy2Pa8sTMR@Dc95W6KFne72n6CVq4OWfNF9U0P0mGqgKelcnKp0r2bnyUUxI1xUacK1I58hnomAwoBvg2X8/CKryL81cB/eB29gn4oC3Nl4F0cdjh658fP7CLwheNhfewwsfXgTPd33MRsTSZ5YB11hIbzQf9EDEygdXATcImo2Bm0Mpu4XNOckLfKfqar@s/igmh/Jc5Sr7BnNN08wYcVWqnjR/)

Unfortunately, the shortest unnamed lambda version is the same as OP's of

```hs
\z g->(.g).z.g
```

at 14 bytes, supporting both versions (just swap `g` and `z` in the argument list for the alternative version).

The shortest pointfree solution I could find was

```hs
(flip=<<).(.).((.).)
```

at 20 bytes (which has the type of `v1`), which is 5 bytes shorter than OP's. For `v2`, I got two different 25 byters.

The reduction steps to reach this one:

```haskell
\f g a b -> f (g a) (g b)
\f g a -> B (f (g a)) g
\f g -> C (\a -> B (f (g a))) g
\f g -> C (B (B B f) g) g
\f g -> (=<<) C (B (B B f)) g
\f -> (=<<) C (B (B B f))
((=<<)C).B.BB
(flip=<<).(.).((.).)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think eta-reduction is severely overrated. I see a lot more attempts at eta-reduction in the wild than I think is reasonable.

So it is in this case: eta-reducing this function is not helpful, I think. It's much more readable and elegant in its full form:

```
f :: (a -> a -> c) -> (a -> b) -> b -> b -> c
f g h a b = g (h a) (h b)
```

---

On a related note, such function exists in the standard libraries. [It's called `on`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-14.18/base-4.12.0.0/Data-Function.html#v:on), and the idea is to use it in infix form, so that it almost reads like English:

```
eqAmounts = (==) `on` amount
cmpNames = compare `on` name
```

Comment: Welcome to the site.  I will say that "readability" and "elegance" are not worth a whole lot here.  The reason eta reduction is popular for golfing is that point free functions don't require costly declarations.  The `on` function that you and flawr pointed out is nice and short though.

Comment: I see. Thank you for pointing out. I will unsubscribe from this site.