# How to golf a fork in Haskell?

Tags: code-golf, tips, haskell

I'm trying to make a pointfree function `f` that can act like APL's dyadic forks/Husk's `§`, so `f g h i a b` equals `g (h a) (i b)`, where `g` is a binary function, `h` and `i` are unary functions, and `a` and `b` are integers (I'm only dealing with integers and not other types right now). I converted the function to pointfree in the following steps, but it's 26 bytes with a lot of parentheses and periods and even a `flip`, so I'd like to know how to golf it.

```haskell
f g h i a b=g(h a)(i b)
f g h i=(.i).g.h
f g h=(.g.h).(.)
f g=(.(.)).(flip(.)).(g.)
f=((.(.)).).((flip(.)).).(.)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY6xDsIwDET3fsUNDLZQPABTpbDzGYkgiUUpFe3/BwNFGRiY7u6dT3IJ8/UyDDWh70GncYE7ogm/lP7kn1XnXEJGgSIgwmcqCEyKyK3yJMqSpXyRAUssJOuVAfMG0qDTx2XhmjythYHWvYf1FnSEx/neAdND7aUNEmjLCHEG7cyQ2zMO9Qk)

Comment: Plugging into pointfree.io gives an 20-byter `((flip.((.).)).).(.)`.

Comment: @Bubbler ...Oh. Can you put that as an answer, with an explanation of how it works? It'd be very helpful.

Comment: The reason I wrote it in a comment is that I don't know how it works :P Btw, should the arguments be ordered exactly like that?

Answer (score 15):

## 18 bytes

```hs
(flip.).(.).((.).)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY87EsIwDET7nGILCmkYuwCqzJieO9A4AX8GEzyE82MEDklBQaXd96RCwY6Xc0rFoW1Bh@EBtccy@D3pT/@5apRy8AiIsOhgPAVYpoiOF2VIR9Zehy8SII016WlLgGQBLsVck6/O0KQELXY@NRWKEzYLZ46l8k@fbLnaOMDgdGuAfI/yxAoOtGbYbgRtJJDaMnbl2btk/VhUn/ML)

Since your function has no argument repetition and no argument deletion, it essentially becomes a BC calculus golf (in Haskell terms, a golf using just `B=(.)` and `C=flip`). I will use B and C combinators and convert to Haskell code later.

```haskell
\g h i a b -> g (h a) (i b)
\g h i a -> B (g (h a)) i
\g h i -> C (\a -> B (g (h a))) i
\g h -> C (\a -> B (g (h a)))

-- choice 1
\g h -> C (B B (B g h))
-- choice 1.1
\g -> B C (B (B B) (B g))
B C.B (B B).B
(flip.).(((.).).).(.)  -- 21 bytes
-- choice 1.2
\g -> B (B C (B B)) (B g)
B (B C (B B)).B
((flip.((.).)).).(.)  -- 20 bytes; pointfree.io

-- choice 2
\g h -> C (B (B B g) h)
\g -> B C (B (B B g))
B C.B.B B
(flip.).(.).((.).)  -- 18 bytes; shortest
```

As a bonus, if you can swap `i` and `a` in the definition of `f`, it becomes an ordered LC and allows a very short form using just `(.)`:

```haskell
\g h a i b -> g (h a) (i b)
\g h a i -> B (g (h a)) i
\g h a -> B (g (h a))
\g h -> B (B B g) h
\g -> B (B B g)
B B (B B)
(.).((.).)  -- 10 bytes
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  It seems like a mechanical process of enumeration.  Why is pointfree.io not able to find the shortest one?  Is the original insight that the problem was equivalent to a BC calculus golf the stumbling block?

Comment: @Jonah The primary reason is that `a.b.c` can be both `(a.b).c` and `a.(b.c)`, which give different results at the end. I'm pretty sure pointfree.io uses only one of the possible abstractions to get *some* correct result.

Comment: what does "BC calculus" mean? Where can I find more info to learn about it?

Comment: B and C are [combinators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic), i.e. essentially functions that are used in a system with no explicit variables. Asking for a point-free definition of a function is more or less asking for a definition in terms of combinators. BC calculus is simply the system you get if you allow combinators B and C (+ applications) only.

Comment: @NooneAtAll To add to zale's comment, BC calculus is equivalent to [linear logic/linear lambda calculus](https://blog.functorial.com/posts/2017-08-05-Embedding-Linear-Lambda-Calculus.html) where each argument is used exactly once in some order.